# Log scrum meeting minutes on Azure devops Boards

Tags: azure, azure-devops, scrum, scrumboard

Our team is using Azure Devops Boards for our sprint planning. We have setup Epic, Feature, backlogs and task and tracking via Kanban boards.

Is there anyway that we can write/log scrum meeting minutes everyday within Azure devops? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of now there is no way to add meeting minutes, however, there are few user voices related to this [`feature`](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/429938/generate-report-like-minute-of-meeting-from-vsts.html) raised by others hopefully implemented in the future.

Alternatively, you can use [`Azure Devop's Wiki`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/wiki/) page to have your content.